# Can excel get a inverse function from a self-defining function? If it cannot, what kind of software can do it?

Tags: matlab, excel-formula, sigmaplot

if I have a self-defining function `y=2x+1`, I want to get its inverse function `X=(Y-1)/2`, Can excel help? or other software like sigmaplot or Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

With MATLAB, if you have ***Symbolic Math Toolbox*** , you can do this using:

```
syms x y;
eqn = y == 2*x - 1 ;

x = solve(eqn,x)
```